# How to convert 8080 type 8 bit parallel interface to I2C interface?

Tags: i2c, spi, lcd, bus

[image]I have a 8080 type 8-bit parallel interface LCD. Is it possible to convert it to I2C interface?

Comment: Why I²C? SPI is much better (use 74x595 shift register).

Comment: I highly suggest you read the datasheet of the LCD driver IC. Most 8080 style driver also support I2c. You just need to set the correct mode and find the pins.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *"**Is it possible to convert it** to I2C interface?"*

Yes, it is.

Build an I2C-node, that will receive all LCD-directed traffic inside I2C-protocol.

And process continuously all this incoming traffic, producing LCD-display hardware interface compatible output, as the device expected to receive and produce ( a touch-screen, isn't it? ) in design and still expects in operation state.

Published specifications tell you the rules for both the ingress and exgress traffic this proxy ought mediate.

---

The same applies to an option, *proposed by [Oandriy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2511795/0andriy) ad-hoc*, not to stick just to **`I2C`**-port, and use rather or instead or either **`SPI`**.